# Header file path

Tags: c++, libraries, libxml

I have installed libxml2 on my machine:

```
sudo aptitude install libxml2
```

But I can't find header files. Where header files are located?

Comment: They're not provided by the `libxml2` package - they're provided by `libxml2-dev - Development files for the GNOME XML library`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing `libxml2-dev` instead.  And then you'll find the header files in:  `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/`.

I checked this (without installing it) by installing the program `apt-file`.  Then, I did:  `sudo apt-file update; sudo apt-file show libxml2-dev`.

Comment: Visiting search results on packages.ubuntu.com as https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libxml2-dev/filelist is good too!